# How to del DataFrame useless rows, make the useful rows index from 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get a DataFrame from an API, but the index is not from 0.
I want to index it from 0,so I tried .reindex().
But it just NA the items before, useful lines still lies from where it from...
How can I index the useful items from 0 in pandas DataFrame?

```
In [29]: a = ts.get_k_data('399300', index=True,start='2015-05-01', end='2015-05
    ...: -31')

In [30]: a
Out[30]: 
          date     open    close     high      low       volume      code
78  2015-05-04  4757.64  4787.74  4795.92  4699.40  377843853.0  sz399300
79  2015-05-05  4785.19  4596.84  4785.19  4572.98  460419626.0  sz399300
80  2015-05-06  4626.23  4553.33  4700.91  4511.76  376073702.0  sz399300
81  2015-05-07  4520.82  4470.09  4546.34  4467.46  297759203.0  sz399300

In [31]: b = a.reindex(list(range(0,80)))

In [32]: b
Out[32]: 
          date     open    close     high      low       volume      code
0          NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN
1          NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN
2          NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN
..         ...      ...      ...      ...      ...          ...       ...
76         NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN
77         NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN          NaN       NaN
78  2015-05-04  4757.64  4787.74  4795.92  4699.40  377843853.0  sz399300
79  2015-05-05  4785.19  4596.84  4785.19  4572.98  460419626.0  sz399300

[80 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do `df.index = pd.RangeIndex(0, df.shape[0])`

to overwrite your index directly, with `reindex` it's effectively keeping the existing index and returning you the rows that correspond to the passed in row values, as they don't exist it displays `NaN`

Example:

```
In[92]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns = list('abc'), index=[3,4,5,10,50])
df

Out[92]: 
           a         b         c
3  -0.185420  0.230181  1.561401
4  -0.142055 -1.130427 -1.209588
5   2.590563  0.367157  1.878946
10  0.317735 -1.578927  0.555270
50  1.424068  0.667701  0.619741

In[93]:
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(0,df.shape[0])
df

Out[93]: 
          a         b         c
0 -0.185420  0.230181  1.561401
1 -0.142055 -1.130427 -1.209588
2  2.590563  0.367157  1.878946
3  0.317735 -1.578927  0.555270
4  1.424068  0.667701  0.619741
```

Here the `RangeIndex` is an optimised Index object for monotonic int indices, you could also do `df.index = np.arange(0, df.shape[0])` but this creates a full range np array which gets converted into a `RangeIndex` anyway. With a `RangeIndex` it just needs to know the start, stop range and the step so it's memory efficient

Alternatively just call [`reset_index(drop=True)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In[94]:
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df

Out[94]: 
          a         b         c
0 -0.185420  0.230181  1.561401
1 -0.142055 -1.130427 -1.209588
2  2.590563  0.367157  1.878946
3  0.317735 -1.578927  0.555270
4  1.424068  0.667701  0.619741
```

This will essentially drop the current index and remake it with the index starting from 0